# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port"

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I write this code for collecting information through email, here i using sendmail plugin, but here its generated an error, that failed to connect to mail server[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzfWt.png)

i Make little changes to php.ini

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i";

 <?php
    $to = 'localhost,wasu3690@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'My subject';
    $txt = 'Hello world!';
    $headers = 'From: wasu3690@gmail.com';

     if (mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers))
            echo "Email Sent";
            else "not sent";
    ini_set("SMTP",'localhost');
    ini_set("smtp_port",25);

    ?>
```

Comment: Is anything running on that port? Use e.g. `swaks` to verify that (provided it's available on MS Windows, I don't know if it is).

Comment: what is swaks?and,how to check swaks -ulrich-eckhardt

Comment: Why are you sending an email to the email address "localhost"?

Comment: Also, as always, in double-quoted PHP strings the backslash character has significant meaning. You *must* double them up in paths on Windows: `C:\\wamp\\sendmail\\..."`.

Comment: sir, still not working sendmail_path ="C:\\wamp\\sendmail\\sendmail.exe -t -i"; @tadman

Comment: Why are you configuring in the INI and *also* in the code? You should pick one, and get that configuration working properly. `ini_set` is normally for shared environments where you can't edit the INI directly.

Comment: `swaks` is http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/. The idea is to make sure you SMTP server works before trying to tackle the problem of accessing it with PHP.

Comment: how to use swaks in the code? @Ulrich Eckhardt

Comment: You don't use it in the code.